# Powershell - converting hex from the registry key

Tags: powershell, registry

I have the following output from an MRU list. How can I convert it to String or ASCII characters?

'gp "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\LastVisitedPidlMRU"'

18           : {80, 0, 120, 0...}
5            : {50, 0, 109, 0...}

Comment: Why are you reading this registry value? What MRU data are you trying to get? There may be a better way than using the registry.  It looks like those values contain binary data as well as text.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `gp "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\LastVisitedPidlMRU"`

gives :

```
PSPath       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\LastVisitedPidlMRU
PSParentPath : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32
PSChildName  : LastVisitedPidlMRU
PSDrive      : HKCU
PSProvider   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
MRUListEx    : {14, 0, 0, 0...}
11           : {114, 0, 117, 0...}
9            : {69, 0, 120, 0...}
19           : {83, 0, 107, 0...}
10           : {78, 0, 79, 0...}
17           : {123, 0, 57, 0...}
15           : {115, 0, 108, 0...}
7            : {123, 0, 57, 0...}
4            : {118, 0, 109, 0...}
21           : {109, 0, 115, 0...}
22           : {100, 0, 101, 0...}
24           : {123, 0, 55, 0...}
8            : {123, 0, 69, 0...}
0            : {123, 0, 69, 0...}
5            : {123, 0, 66, 0...}
12           : {83, 0, 110, 0...}
20           : {123, 0, 55, 0...}
23           : {83, 0, 99, 0...}
2            : {65, 0, 99, 0...}
16           : {110, 0, 111, 0...}
1            : {105, 0, 101, 0...}
18           : {75, 0, 105, 0...}
6            : {99, 0, 104, 0...}
13           : {123, 0, 55, 0...}
3            : {123, 0, 54, 0...}
14           : {123, 0, 57, 0...}
```

You can try:

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString((gp "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\LastVisitedPidlMRU")."11")
```

This not very good, but it can help

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Get-RegistryKeyValue](http://get-carbon.org/help/Get-RegistryKeyValue.html) from the Carbon PowerShell module.  It will return this key value as an array, which you can then decode:

```
$path = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\LastVisitedPidlMRU'
$result = Get-RegistryKeyValue -Path $path -Name 0
[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString( $result )
```

But it looks like that registry value contains more than just text.

*DISCLAIMER*: I am the creator/maintainer of the Carbon module.

Answer (score 2):

Using [this tip](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/05/11/use-powershell-to-enumerate-registry-property-values.aspx) from the *Hey, Scripting Guy!* blog you could do something like this:

```
$key = "HKCU:\Softw...dlMRU"
Get-Item $key | select -Expand property | % {
  $value = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name $_).$_
  [System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetString($value)
}
```

Note that the values probably contain non-printable characters, so that alone won't suffice. You'll have to do some additional cleanup, e.g. by appending `-replace '[\x01-\x1F]'` to the `GetString()` call.